# In ATG, how can I disallow the creation of a Repository Item of a super type while allowing creation of each subtype in the BCC?

Tags: repository, atg, bcc, oracle-commerce

Let's say I have a content repository with an item descriptor, say TypeA.

It has two subtypes TypeX an TypeY

In the BCC, I want authors to be able to create content of type TypeX and TypeY, but not TypeA.

Comment: It's basic repository inheritance, but I cannot remember

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you can do both - if only I could have seen the wood for the trees when RTFM.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24152_01/Platform.10-1/ATGRepositoryGuide/html/s0611itemdescriptorinheritance01.html

Replace "clothing" with TypeA, "shirt" with TypeX and "shorts" with TypeY

```
<!-- The "clothing" item type, a base type -->
<item-descriptor name="clothing" sub-type-property="type">

  <!-- This is the primary table that holds clothing data -->
  <table name="clothing" type="primary" id-column-names="id">
    <property name="type" data-type="enumerated">
      <option value="shirt"/>
      <option value="shorts"/>
    </property>
    <property name="name"/>
    <property name="description"/>
    <property name="color"/>
    <property name="size"/>
    <property name="shippingWeight"/>
  </table>
</item-descriptor>

<!-- The "shirt" item type is a subclass of "clothing" -->
<item-descriptor name="shirt" super-type="clothing" sub-type-value="shirt">
  <table name="shirt" type="auxiliary" id-column-names="id">
    <property name="season"/>
  </table>
</item-descriptor>

<!-- The "shorts" item type, now a subclass of "clothing" -->
<item-descriptor name="shorts" super-type="clothing" sub-type-value="shorts">
  <table name="shorts" type="auxiliary" id-column-names="id">
    <property name="pleated" data-type="boolean"/>
  </table>
</item-descriptor>
```

and, if you *want* TypeA to be instantiatable, then

```
<!-- The "clothing" item type, a base type -->
<item-descriptor name="clothing" sub-type-property="type"
                                 sub-type-value="clothing">
  <!-- This is the primary table that holds clothing data -->
  <table name="clothing" type="primary" id-column-names="id">
    <property name="type" data-type="enumerated">
      <option value="clothing"/>
      <option value="shirt"/>
      <option value="shorts"/>
    <property/>
   ...
```